# FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow() Problems with React JS

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs

I'm using the Facebook [JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript) inside of a [React JS](https://facebook.github.io/react/) app.

As per the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow), I'm calling `FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow()` after the SDK is loaded in.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v2.5'
    });

    FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();

    ReactDOM.render(routes, document.getElementById('app'));
};
```

The `FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow()` method runs a 100ms interval that resizes the canvas to fit the content of an app, however I still see a scroll in the app.

I'm using [React Router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router), so the app is a single page app, which is what I think might be causing the problems for me. Is this the case or am I doing something else incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using React (and React Router) for Facebook Apps too, should be completely irrelevant for your case. Make sure the content width is 810px max, else it will show both scrollbars. You can also use `overflow:hidden` to hide the scrollbars. I could tell more with a test link.

**Edit: It does not work with `height:100%`, set your container to a fixed height or remove the height setting.**

Comment: Here is the [link to the app](https://www.facebook.com/Finer-Vision-Test-Page-655649234468332/app/1522549951389751) within Facebook

Comment: That worked, can you edit your answer to more directly answer mine so that other people with this problem can see this more clearly? Thanks.